# OData HTML Visualizer

Tags: odata

I developed an OData web services which exposes my entity framework model, now I need to develop a Query Builder like this,

http://odata.intel.com/QueryBuilder

Are there any HTML or JS plugin I could use, I am open to JQuery or Angularjs, bootstrap or any other plugin available instead of recreating wheel.

Comment: I think this is better suited on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/